# C++ Looking up Types At Runtime

Tags: c++, types

I have a class parameterised by some template parameters:

```
template<typename Scalar, typename Integrator, int Dimension>
class foo;
```

Each of the template parameters can be one of a few possible types.  Currently the type of foo used is hard-coded in man `typedef foo<...> foo_type`.  I wish to adapt my program so that a collection of `foo`'s are supported; something like:

```
if (desired_foo_str == "2DSimpleFloat")
{
    foo<float,Simple,2>(params).method();
}
else if (desired_foo_str == "3DSimpleDouble")
{
    foo<double,Simple,3>(params).method();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Unsupported foo."
}
```

The interface of foo does not depend on its template parameters.  My question is how can I improve this solution?  I know `boost::mpl` provides a type vector but it seems more for compile time reductions as opposed to run-time switching.

**Clarification**

Lets say (this is a simplification) that my program takes a set of points in N-dimensions (provided by the user) and integrates them.  Certain combinations of dimensions, integration methods and scalar types can be accelerated by SIMD (hence the use of template parameters).  All combinations of `foo<A,B,N>` are valid however different users (all of whom will have compiled my program) will require only a couple of specific specializations for their work.  I wish to allow for:

```
$ integrate --method=2DSimpleFloat mypoints2d.dat
$ integrate --methid=3DSimpleDouble mypoints3d.dat
```

so run-time selection of what method they wish to use.  I am wondering what kind of frame-work best allows me to associate types with strings such that I can better handle the above scenario.

Comment: Does it have to be a string comparison that determines the type of `foo` you end up with? What is `params`? Does that contain any information that determines the template parameters?

Comment: The parameters are the same for all template parameters and do not determine them.  As I need to pick the type of `foo` to use at runtime based off of user-provided input it probably does have to be a string.

Comment: Just for solving this exact problem at hand, regardless of whether there's a better way to implement what you're doing: partial template specialization for just your supported types? Otherwise this feels like it calls for Alexandrescu's typelists...

Comment: reading your clarification confirms my suspicion of use .. I would code an N-D,any type case as templates, then over-ride the cases that can use SIMD intrinsics. Perhaps wrap those implementations in #defines for cross-platform support (ready to compile your program on other CPU's such as ARM)

Comment: @centaurian_slug The SIMD stuff is all taken care of by the vector math library I am using.  My issue is how a user can say **at runtime** what template specialisation they want from those compiled into the program.  "Unsupported" in this context means "not compiled into the program".

Comment: fair enough. I presume you're using templates because you have some reusable setup code formatting data for the library calls perhaps. Runtime selection does of course need some sort of table or 'if' based dispatch

Answer (score 2):

You could make templated default method which throws an error, and template-specializations per combination that you support.

```
class Simple {};
template<typename Scalar, typename Integrator, int Dimension>
class foo
{
public:
  void method();
  foo() {}
};

// default implementation throws an error
template<typename Scalar, typename Integrator, int Dimension>
void foo<Scalar,Integrator,Dimension>::method() {  cout << "unsupported\n"; };

// override default for supported cases:-
template<>
void foo<double,Simple,2>::method() { cout <<"method1\n"; };

template<>
void foo<double,Simple,3>::method() { cout <<"method2\n"; };

// test program
void main() {
   foo<float,Simple,2> a; a.method(); // output "unsupported"
   foo<double,Simple,2> b; b.method(); // output "method1"
   foo<double,Simple,3> c; c.method(); // output "method2"
}
```

You should be able to mix general purpose implementations and special purpose overides freely throughout the class; (e.g. perhaps some permeation can be handled with SIMD intrinsics or whatever)

If all the class methods were identical and generic, a convenient way to restrict use might be to restrict the constructor so that undesired cases can't be instantiated

in general if the mechanisms of overloading and templates are being used correctly, you should be able to avoid checking types manually where they're used.
This can all work compile time statically linked without any pointers or virtual dispatch.

If the supported implementations are to be the same, the over-rides can be wrappers to direct to another templated method as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't provide enough information for a complete answer, but I have a hunch: Perhaps you should look into refactoring your code so as to separate the part that is independent of the parameters from the code that depends on the template parameters.

The typical example is taken from Scott Meyers's book. Suppose you have a square matrix multiplicator, and you write this as a full template:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
Matrix<T, N> multiply(Matrix<T, N>, Matrix<T, N>)
{
   // heavy code
}
```

With this setup, the compiler would generate a *separate* piece of code for each size value `N`! That's potentially a lot of code, and all that `N` provides is a bound in a loop.

So the suggestion here is to turn compile-time into *runtime* parameters and refactor the workload into a separate function, and only use template *stubs* to dispatch the call:

```
template <typename T>
void multiply_impl(unsigned int N,
                   MatrixBuf<T> const & in1, MatrixBuf<T> const & in1,
                   MatrixBuf<T> & out)
{
   // heavy work
}

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
Matrix<T, N> multiply(Matrix<T, N> const & in1, Matrix<T, N> const & in1)
{
  Matrix<T, N> out;
  multiply_impl(N, in1.buf(), in2.buf(), out.buf());
}
```

You could do something similar: Put all the argument-independent code in a base class, and make the derived classes templates. The runtime can then use a factory function to create the correct concrete instance at runtime. As an alternative to inheritance you can also make a type-erasing wrapper class that contains a private pointer-to-base, and the runtime populates this with concrete derived implementation instances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guesing you are looking for register pattern. This is only my draft, so don't rely on it.

```
class AbstractFooFactory
{
     virtual AbstractFoo* create( ParamsType cons& params ) = 0;
     // or construct on stack and call .method()
     virtual void createAndCallMethod( ParamsType cons& params ) = 0;
};

class FooRegister
{
   ~FooRegister(); // delete all pointers
   template< typename FooFactory >
   void operator() ( FooFactory const & factory ) // for boost::mpl:for_each 
   { map[factory.getName()]= new FooFactory( factory ); }
   AbstractFooFactory* get( std::string name );
   std::map< std::string , AbstractFooFactory* > map;
};

template< typename Scalar, typename Integrator, typename Dimension >
class FooFactory: public AbstractFooFactory
{
    typedef FooFactory<Scalar, Integrator, Dimension > type; // Metafunction
    std::string getName(); // this will be a bit hard to implement
    AbstractFoo* create( ParamsType cons& params );
    void createAndCallMethod( ParamsType cons& params );
};
```

Simple trails may be used for storing type names:

```
template< typename Type >
struct NameTrails
{
    static const char const* value;
};

template<> const char const* NameTrails<int>::value = "Int";
template<> const char const* NameTrails<float>::value = "Float";
template<> const char const* NameTrails<double>::value = "Double";
template<> const char const* NameTrails<Simple>::value = "Simple";
template<> const char const* NameTrails<Complex>::value = "Complex";

template< typename Scalar, typename Integrator, typename Dimension >
std::string FooFactory::getName() 
{
  return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( Dimension::value ) + "D"
         + NameTrails< Integrator >::value
         + NameTrails< Scalar >::value;
}
```

And now you need to register all types using mpl::for_each:

```
FooRegister fooRegister;

typedef boost::mpl::vector<Simple,Complex> IntegratorsList;
typedef boost::mpl::vector<int,float,double> ScalarsList;
typedef boost::mpl::range_c<int,1,4> DimensionsList;

typedef boost::mpl::vector< 
     boost::mpl::vector< Simple, float, boost::mpl::int_<2> >,
     boost::mpl::vector< Simple, double, boost::mpl::int_<3> >,
    ... other types or full cross join ... > FooList;

boost::mpl::for_each< FooList, boost::mpl::quote3<FooFactory> >( 
    boost::ref(fooRegister) );
```

What i don't know is how to cross join `IntegratorsList, ScalarList, range_c<int,1,4>` to constuct full FooList.

```
fooRegister.get("2DSimpleFloat")->createAndCallMethod(params);
```

You probably want to do this statically, so yes it is possible, but i find it rather difficult to achieve better performance then a simple dynamic map or hash map.

Comment: As something of a simplification only a few specific methods are required -- as opposed to all possible combinations.

Comment: So i think using `if` tree is best effort to get it as simple as it can be. You may put `static std::string getName();` inside foo. Or maybe some use of preprocessor?